# css center problem

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="headermain">
 <div id="logo">
            <a href="#">net</a>
        </div>
```

i'm unable to center the #logo div inside of #headermain

i'm giving margin:auto; but nothing happends. #headermain is also centered by using margin:auto;

Comment: Give us some css to look at ...

Comment: Are you using `margin:auto;` or `margin-left:auto;` and `margin-right:auto;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `width` property :

```css
 #headermain { width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; }
 #logo { width: 400px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Answer (score 1):

`div#logo` must have a `width` property for `margin: auto;` to work

Answer (score 1):

Is it? #logo { text-align: center }

Comment: @susan here is a working example(from what we know so far) http://jsfiddle.net/CdNyb/